# How to get a sider filling whole available height.

Tags: reactjs, layout, antd

I started React based application and i have a ant-design a basic layout with top navbar, sidebar, footer and content area, my code is as following.

```
    <Layout>
          <Header>
              <TopNavBar/>
          </Header>
          <Layout>
              <Sider className='sider'>
                  <div  >
                       side nav

                  </div>
              </Sider>
              <Content>main content</Content>

              </Layout>
          <Footer>Footer</Footer>
      </Layout>
```

I want to get a result similar to the representation below, with a sidebar who fill whole available page height

[image]

I tried to add the following cCSS class to my sider

```
.sider {
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

without getting what I want, my sidebar is bigger than available space it's scrolling,the height that exceeds is the height of my header and footer.

I also tried with flexbox but without success,  there is any clean way to get the desired result? I thought to do this using the javascript to calculate the available height and set the CSS class.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code

```
.menu-style {
overflow: auto;
height: 100vh;
width: 200px;
position: fixed;
left: 0;
background-color: #393f4a;
z-index: 3 ;
border-right : 0;
```

}